# GetOrgChart jquery need to warp text

Tags: javascript, jquery, getorgchart

How do I wrap text on `getOrgChart`. I only need to display to fields name and address. Is there a way to remove the other fields like (tel, email) and warp text so it display the whole text completely instead of...

Comment: Please, can you provide some code about what you already have? And also complete you question.

Comment: hi dont have a code was just looking at the demo at http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Create-Your-Own-Theme-3, when i edit the email address to a long text. The full text was not shown.  is it possible to wrap the email address to show all the text?

Comment: sorry could not attach image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreignObject and html for the theme of GetOrgChart

```
<foreignObject width="200" height="200">
  <p>Text goes here</p>
</foreignObject>
```

Comment: Hi can you help point to a link with a demo of using foreignObject?  Would foreignObject be supported by IE?